# Payara Server generates empty OpenAPI documentation

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, payara

Hello I am deploying an EAR on Payara Server, the EAR contains some WARs and some other modules. In one of the WARs I have a JAX-RS REST API, I wanted to generate an OpenAPI document, I saw that Payara generates it by default by using Eclipse MicroProfile, but the problem is that the resulting OpenAPI doesn't have any paths listed despite that I have a few working methods that I have annotated with @GET and @POST in my API WAR.

I added my RestApplication class that extends Application like so:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

And my endpoint class looks like so:

```
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/ping")
    public Response ping() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Ping works").build();
    }
}
```

The REST API works as expected but the resulting openapi.yaml is:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Deployed Resources
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: http://192.168.5.5:8080/__wstx-services
  description: Default Server.
- url: https://192.168.5.5:8181/__wstx-services
  description: Default Server.
paths: {}
components: {}
```

So the endpoint is not present in the OpenAPI documentation, am I missing something?